# Using Javascript in asp.net for timepicker control

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, timepicker

I'm trying to use this TimePicker Control http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ but I'm new in web programming so I need a little help,

I have this so far but is not working

```html
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<link href="../Content/css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upEdit" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="basic_example" id="basic_example" class="hasDatepicker" >
            <script type="text/javascript">
              function timepic() {
                $('#basic_example').timepicker(
                  $.timepicker.regional['es'])
              };
            </script>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you remove update panel check once it is working or not?

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Where you call `timepic()`?? ... should be within `$(document).ready(function(){ // code here})`

Comment: Check your browser console for any errors. Are you including all the preliminary libraries (jQuery & jQuery UI) to your project?

Comment: Yes they are included [Image](http://s13.postimg.org/szpajvtxz/Sin_t_tulo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your javascript function to,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#basic_example').timepicker(
        $.timepicker.regional['es'])
});
```

Add it at the end of page.

Comment: like this?     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#basic_example').timepicker(
                $.timepicker.regional['es'])
        });
    </script>

Comment: This is a img of what I have >.< (http://s28.postimg.org/3phzf5osd/Sin_t_tulo.png)

Comment: No, I give up with this, I'll find another way to do it =/

Comment: Ok, I also used same thing but different jquery for time picker.